Unit testing on theHero module
I have an error problem when doing unit testing, I tested this code
//* images

//* custom components
import RoutingPage from '../../../../../../../src/components/RoutingPage';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const CustomImage = dynamic(() => import('../../../../../../../src/components/Image'), { ssr: false });

const Hero = () => {
  const { data } = useSelector((state: any) => state?.careerFriendsBanner);

  return (
    <section className="mb-10">
      {/* breadcrumb */}
      <RoutingPage route={['Beranda', 'Gabung', 'Karir Page', 'LifeFriends Activity']} url1={'/careers'} />

      {/* thumbnail hero */}
      <section>
        <div className="friends-wrap-thumbnail position-relative">
          <div className="d-none d-md-flex">
            {/* <Image
              src={config.BASE_URL_IMG + data?.desktop_link}
              alt={data?.alt_text}
              objectFit="cover"
              layout="fill"
              objectPosition="top"
              priority
              placeholder="blur"
              blurDataURL={CareerFriendHero}
              style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }}
            /> */}

            <CustomImage link={data?.desktop_link} alt={data?.alt_text} layout="fill" style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }} />
          </div>
          <div className="d-md-none">
            {/* <Image
              src={
                data?.mobile_link ? config.BASE_URL_IMG + data?.mobile_link : config.BASE_URL_IMG + data?.desktop_link
              }
              alt={data?.alt_text}
              objectFit="cover"
              layout="fill"
              objectPosition="top"
              priority
              placeholder="blur"
              blurDataURL={CareerFriendHero}
              style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }}
            /> */}
            <CustomImage
              link={data?.mobile_link ? data?.mobile_link : data?.desktop_link}
              alt={data?.alt_text}
              layout="fill"
              style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="friends-wrap-thumbnail-overlay"></div>
          <div className="container">
            {/* heading web */}
            <div className="container friends-wraper-heading" style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 10, zIndex: 1 }}>
              <h1 className="text-white friends-text-title">{data?.title}</h1>
              <p className="text-white">{data?.description}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="container friends-wraper-heading-mobile">
          {/* heading mobile */}
          <div className="w-100 mt-5 mb-md-10">
            <h1 className="text-black text-center friends-text-title-mobile">{data?.title}</h1>
            <p className="friends-text-subtitle-mobile text-center fs-14 m-0 p-0">{data?.description}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Hero;


but an error occurred like this
error doing unit testing
in the explanation there is a problem with the RoutingPage component but I analyzed that there is no problem with this component.
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function RoutingPage({ route, url1 }: any) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const lastIndex = route?.[route.length - 1];

  return (
    <div
      className="ps-lg-17 d-none w-100 d-md-flex align-items-center "
      style={{ backgroundColor: '#EDEFF2', height: '44px' }}
    >
      <div className="container route-page mt-4">
        {route?.map((item: any, index: any) => (
          <div key={index} className="d-inline">
            <span style={item === lastIndex ? { color: '#000c17' } : { color: '##000C17', fontWeight: 'normal' }}>
              {item === route[0] ? (
                <p className="d-inline-block h-100 pointer-menu" onClick={() => router.push('/')}>
                  {item}
                </p>
              ) : item === route[1] ? (
                <p className="d-inline-block h-100 pointer-menu" onClick={() => router.push(url1)}>
                  {item}
                </p>
              ) : item === route[route.length - 1] ? (
                <p className="d-inline-block h-100 pointer-menu" onClick={() => router.push(router.asPath)}>
                  {item}
                </p>
              ) : (
                <p className="d-inline-block h-100 pointer-menu" onClick={() => router.push(url1)}>
                  {item}
                </p>
              )}{' '}
              {item === lastIndex ? (
                ''
              ) : (
                <span
                  style={{
                    color: '#ED1C24'
                  }}
                >
                  /{' '}
                </span>
              )}
            </span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


what do I need to do regarding this problem? please help me with this problem.
following the unit test that I made
import Hero from '../../../../../pages/modules/join/pages/careers/life-friends/components/Hero';
import { describe, test, expect } from 'vitest'; // Import Vitest
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'; // Tetap menggunakan @testing-library/react
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

// Mock data untuk state useSelector
const careerFriendsBannerReducer = (
    state = {
        data: {
            careerFriendBanner: {
                title: "Judul Hero",
                description: "Deskripsi Hero",
                desktop_link: "/images/hero-desktop.jpg",
                mobile_link: "/images/hero-mobile.jpg",
                alt_text: "Hero Image",
            }
        }
    }
) => state;

const mockData = {
    title: "Judul Hero",
    description: "Deskripsi Hero",
    desktop_link: "/images/hero-desktop.jpg",
    mobile_link: "/images/hero-mobile.jpg",
    alt_text: "Hero Image",
}

describe('Komponen Hero', () => {
  test('harusnya merender heading dan gambar untuk desktop', () => {
    const store = configureStore({
        reducer: {
            careerFriendsBanner: careerFriendsBannerReducer
        }
    })
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Hero />
        </Provider>
    );

    // Cek elemen heading
    const heading = screen.getByText(mockData.title);
    expect(heading).toBeTruthy();

    // Cek elemen gambar desktop
    const imageDesktop = screen.getByAltText(mockData.alt_text) as HTMLImageElement;
    expect(imageDesktop).toBeTruthy();
    expect(imageDesktop.src).toContain(mockData.desktop_link);
  });

});

The expectation that I want is that the test case matches the result being tested.
